# ¿Cuál es el origen del modismo «tener que ver con»?

Tags: modismos, etimología

[***Tener que ver con***](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/tener_que_ver_con) significa tener una relación/relevancia/conexión lógica con. Por ejemplo:

> [La caída del IBEX no tiene nada que ver con la situación de España](http://www.elmundo.es/economia/2015/08/24/55db7c72268e3e6b6d8b458f.html)

Pero no es claro lo que ***ver*** significa en el modismo. Entonces, ¿cómo asumió *tener que ver con* su significado?

Existen también preguntas sobre el [modismo portugués equivalente](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/851/tem-a-ver-qual-%C3%A9-a-origem-desta-express%C3%A3o) (en portugués e inglés) y el [equivalente francés](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/16499/quelle-est-l-origine-de-l-expression-avoir-%C3%A0-voir) La versión portuguesa es la más antigua, pero solamente tienen respuestas especulativas.

Comment: Si existen en los demás idiomas de origen latín, puede que origine en este.  Yo he encontrado la frase (con variaciones como *haber que ver*) en documentos fechados tan temprano como el 1443 Oculta Filosofía Lib. 1 : «Que tienen que ver eſtas marauillas con que vna miſma coſa ſeatrina, y vna?» (p. 298 de *Oculta Filosofía Lib. 1*: https://books.google.com/books?id=kKFdLDaPADMC&pg=PA296&dq=%22que+ver%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCUQ6AEwAWoVChMI8s3mzpj4yAIVDO4mCh0LDwDC#v=onepage&q=%22que%20ver%22&f=false ) Será difícil encontrar con más anterioridad porque estas fechas predatan los incunables

Comment: Excepto... esta fecha tiene que estar errada — los incunables ni aparecieron en la península hasta finales del siglo XVIII y su tipografía es aurisecular.  El ejemplo más antiguo que encuentro a una búsqueda rápida es este en castellano en forma *haber que ver* https://books.google.com/books?id=jF6_ATMIHasC&pg=PT241&dq=%22que+ver%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCMQ6AEwATgUahUKEwiw6a_6m_jIAhWK6iYKHcBKBDE#v=onepage&q=%22que%20ver%22&f=false

Comment: También encontré una en galaicoportugués en la formar *ter que ver* en 1601 https://books.google.com/books?id=B8Ewpj-QkMsC&pg=PA46&dq=%22que+ver%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CFcQ6AEwCGoVChMI3YKpupj4yAIVQUkmCh3DoQZ6#v=onepage&q=%22que%20ver%22&f=false   Puede que sea una buena pregunta para Linguistics.SE ya que se trata de varios idiomas.

Comment: El primero autor és Juan Eusebio Nieremberg (1595-1658). En el último, Francisco Rodrigues Lobo, en “não tendes que ver mais* y “tanto mais temos que ver”, *ver* es en sentido literal, no de *relación*.

Comment: En el Fuero Real, *haber que ver con ella* parece ser un eufemismo para *tener relaciones sexuales*

Comment: @guifa: Crees que ***que ver*** en ***haber que ver*** pueda significar ***asunto***, no solamente amoroso, pero algo que merezca ser visto? Esto solucionaría todos lo problemas.

Comment: Caramba, [puse una recompensa](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/posts/15282/revisions) para intentar conseguir alguna respuesta interesante pero parece que nadie pudo encontar el tiempo y las ganas para hacerlo : )

Comment: @fedorqui Muchas gracias por la recompensa. Pena que nadie haya intentado.

Answer (score 2):

Al igual que en español existe en francés.

Ejemplo:

> Qué tiene que ver esto con

Traducción:

> Qu'est-ce que cela a à voir avec

Sin embargo, no existe en inglés donde se usa el verbo hacer *(to do)*.

Qué tiene que ver esto con = *What has this to do with*

En esto se parece el inglés al latín.

tener que ver => haber que ver => habens facere (literalmente: *haber que hacer*)

Comment: Se me ocurre que la introducción del verbo "ver" puede haber ocurrido primero en francés y luego pasó al español.


Qu'est-ce que cela a avoir avec = Qué tiene que haber/tener esto con.


Por separación de "avoir" en "à voir".


Qu'est-ce que cela a à voir avec = Qué tiene que ver esto con.

Answer (score 2):

Lo que dijo GMC con respeto a la conexión entre el francés y el español tiene sentido para mí. Que yo sepa, no se usa el verbo *ver* en el sentido de 'tener relacionces' en otros idiomas europeas, sino el verbo *hacer*. Por ejemplo, así se traduce la frase "¿Que tiene que ver con eso?" en varios idiomas:

Alemán: Was hat das damit zu **tun**?

Italiano: Che cosa ha a che **fare** con esso?

Polaco: Co to ma wspólnego z tym **zrobić**?

Con respecto a ésta forma gramática, el español y el francés me parecen únicos pero me temo que no sé por qué será eso.

Comment: Se usa en portugués (ver pergunta) e en italiano, [avere a che vedere con](http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/V/vedere.php?refresh_ce).

Comment: Ay, gracias que no sabía. Será por mi pobre mando del italiano que no conocía esa expresión. :-) Entonces supongo que la explanación de por que se usa "ver con" será algo más profundo que una simple peculiaridad español/francés...